# Install additional version of WebStorm on same Mac machine

Tags: webstorm

Few years ago I did buy WebStorm version 6.
Day ago I renew my License and get WebStrom version 10.
My question is can I install new WebStorm( v.10 ) on same MAC machine with (v.6 ) ? And don't break previous v.6 installation.
And also use both version for different projects.

- Thanks, Herclia

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with IntelliJ by renaming the existing app.

Also when you attempt to move the new one into Applications folder  you will get a prompt "WebStorm already exists in this location." with the options to Keep Both, Stop or Replace. If you choose Keep Both the new one will have "copy" appended to the name.

A possible problem though is that when you open your project in the newer version it might get upgraded. Not sure if you will be able to open it in the older version.

Comment: You will be able to convert the project back to the older version if you want it to.